# How to find $\int_0^{2\pi}\log(\alpha+\beta\cos(x))\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a closed-form formula for the following integral

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\log(\alpha+\beta\cos(x))\mathrm{d}x
$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants which assure that $\alpha+\beta\cos(x)>0$ for any $x\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Mathematica (2014 version) cannot find a solution, so things are looking bleak.

Comment: There is (in terms of the polygarithm function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I(\alpha,\,\beta)=\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(\alpha+\beta\cos x)\mathrm dx.\tag1$$ We have $\alpha>\beta\geq0$. Since from (1) 
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial\alpha}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta\cos x}\mathrm dx=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}$$
we can integrate with respect to $\alpha$
$$I(\alpha,\beta)=2\pi\ln\left(\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\right)+C(\beta)\tag 2$$
Now using (1) again
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial\beta}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos x}{\alpha+\beta\cos x}\mathrm dx=\frac{2\pi}\beta\frac{-\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}=\frac{-2\pi\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\left(\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\right)}$$
on the one hand, and derivating (2) with respect to $\beta$
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial\beta}=\frac{-2\pi\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\left(\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\right)}+C'(\beta)$$
we conclude that $C'(\beta)=0$. Now we use the value $I(\alpha,0)=2\pi\ln \alpha=2\pi\ln(2\alpha)+C(0)$ so we get
$$I(\alpha,\beta)=2\pi\ln\left(\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\right)-2\pi
\ln2.$$

**Note**
To compute the integral, I used the exponential decomposition of $\cos$
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial\alpha}=
  \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta\cos x}\mathrm dx=
  \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}}{2\alpha\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}+\beta\mathrm e^{2\mathrm ix}+\beta}\mathrm dx$$
The I wrote this integral as a contour integral
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial\alpha}=-2\mathrm i\oint_{\mathcal C(0,1)}\frac{\mathrm dz}{\beta z^2+2\alpha z+\beta}.$$
Since $$\beta z^2+2\alpha z+\beta=\beta\left(z+\frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{\beta}\right)\left(z+\frac{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{\beta}\right)=\beta(z-z_+)(z-z_-)$$
one can use the residue theorem. There is only one residue inside the unit disc (because $z_+z_-=1$), at $z_-= -(\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})/\beta$ and the result is 
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial\alpha}=-2\mathrm i\frac{2\pi \mathrm i}{\beta(z_--z_+)}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}.$$
The integral $\frac{\partial I}{\partial\beta}$ is obtained in the same way,
we get 
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial\beta}=-\mathrm i\oint_{\mathcal C(0,1)}\frac{z+z^{-1}}{\beta z^2+2\alpha z+\beta}\mathrm dz=-\mathrm i\frac{2\pi\mathrm i(z_-+z_-^{-1})}{\beta(z_--z_+)}-\mathrm i\frac{2\pi\mathrm i}\beta=\frac{2\pi}{\beta}\frac{-\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}$$
beacuse there is a second pole at $z=0$.

Comment: If you multiply the last $\ln 2$ with $2\pi$ I agree with you...

Comment: Thanks for you comment ! Corrected

Comment: Good solution Tom +1

Comment: How do you get the first antiderivative ? This seems to be the hardest step.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Thanks for your comment,  I have added the computation of the integrals.

Comment: @Tom-Tom: thanks for adding the details. This is indirectly confirmed by feeding Wolfram Integrator with $1/(1+\cos(\theta)\cos(x))$ ($\cos(\theta)$ required to enforce complex roots): the antiderivative has a $2\csc(\theta)$ coefficient which multiplies the $\pi$ argument jump of an $\arctan$.

Comment: @Tom-Tom: another check is made possible by the simple relation $\alpha I'_\alpha+\beta I'_\beta=2\pi$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. 1st reply: I don't manage to see the result (Wolfram Alpha doesn't give me any). 2nd reply, very clever way to find $I'_\beta$ !

Comment: @Tom-Tom: ask for the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 5):

$$I-2\pi\ln(\alpha)=\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(1+s\cos(x))dx=-\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-s)^k\cos^k(x)}kdx\\
=-\pi\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k4^k}\binom{2k}ks^{2k},$$ where $s=\frac\beta\alpha$, $|s|<1$.

Comment: Ooops, a $k$ was missing in the denominator, very sorry. But then it can be accounted for by integrating the function applied to argument $\sqrt s$ !?

Comment: OK, let me try again $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k4^k}\binom{2k}ks^{2k}=\log (4)-2 \log \left(1+\sqrt{1-s^2}\right)$$

Comment: Seems to get closer to Jason's answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's try the famous Feynman's trick!

Let $I(\beta)$ be your integral. Then$$I'(\beta)=\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{\cos x }{\alpha+\beta\cos x}\mathrm{d} x. $$
Using the $t$-substitution $t=\tan x/2$, we will get 
$$I'(\beta)=\frac {2\pi} {\beta} -\frac{2\alpha\pi}{\beta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}.$$
Integrating it, $$I(\beta)=2\pi\log\beta+2\pi\alpha\operatorname{sech}^{-1}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}+C.$$

Comment: As per the above comment I was expecting $- \beta \sin(x)$ in the numerator of the integrand of $I'(\beta)$.

Comment: The derivative is correct, since it is with respect to $\beta$ and not $x$.

Comment: @mickep Ah! My mistake, I would have liked to have seen $I'(\beta)$ written as $\frac{\partial I}{\partial \beta}$. Thanks.

Comment: However, when doing the $t=\tan x/2$ one should be a bit careful, since the interval $0<x<2\pi$ will include singularities of the tangent function. (I don't claim Jason to be wrong.)

Comment: After fixing an error, I now need to rethink what value of beta I should put in to find C.

Comment: It might be easier if you start out by differentiating by $\alpha$ instead.

Comment: @mickep: not really, $\alpha I'_\alpha+\beta I'_\beta=2\pi$, the two derivatives are very similar.

Comment: Well, I still thing the path of calculations is "slimmer" when differentiating w.r.t. $\alpha$.